# XNA 4.0 Menu with Multiple buttons, only one drawing

Tags: c#, menu, xna-4.0

I am currently making a video game for a university project. Our teacher provided us with plenty tutorials on topics he hasn't had time to cover. My game menu has all images necessary, a .JPG Menu Background and 3 .PNG files for the buttons (they come in a circle shape).

I have followed Oyyou's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54L_w0PiRa8) and have managed to get everything to work except to draw the other 2 buttons I have. I noticed the issue is in the Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) method,

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\MainMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600), Color.White);

btnStartGame.Draw(spriteBatch);

btnExitGame.Draw(spriteBatch);

btnEnterCode.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

The only button that shows up on the menu screen is the first one to be declared (btn startGame). If I comment it out, the next one will display. All three buttons are active and if clicked do as they are programmed to, but they are invisible. Anyone has stumbled upon this issue before?

// Code behind button class as requested: ALSO! TileEngine is refferenced both in main game project and in a Level Edtior project, but it is not needed in this case.

Regarding the divide / but double, I now realised it was good to make 3 different classes identical to this because each button has a different Width and Height. To get them right is just trial and error, then in Game1.cs adjusting the position of each button by calling buttonName.SetPosition(new Vector2(x, y);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using TileEngine;

namespace TimerGame.MenuButtons
{
    class ButtonStart  // the other 2 classes have different name of course
    {

        Texture2D texture;
        Vector2 position;
        Rectangle rectangle;

        Color colour = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);

        public Vector2 size;

        public ButtonStart(Texture2D newTexture, GraphicsDevice graphics)
        {
            texture = newTexture;

            size = new Vector2(graphics.Viewport.Width / 5.4f, graphics.Viewport.Height / 8.7f);   // these doubles varry as each button has different dimensions
        }

        bool down;
        public bool isClicked;

        public void Update(MouseState mouse)
        {
            rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y,
                (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);

            Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);

            if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))  // makes buttons flash softly
            {
                if (colour.A == 255) down = false;

                if (colour.A == 201) down = true; // minimum amout to drop color

                if (down) colour.A += 3;  // amount by which to drop
                else colour.A -= 3;

                if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                    isClicked = true;
            }

            else if (colour.A < 255)
            {
                colour.A += 3;  // amount by which to increase
                isClicked = false;
            }
        }

        public void SetPosition(Vector2 newPosition)
        {
            position = newPosition;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, colour);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If done correctly they should all show. Can you show us the code for the buttons ?  Also in spriteBatch.Draw it is bad to continually load the Texture2D. You should store that and the rectangle into a global variable.

Comment: Are the other textures loaded correctly? You also shouldn't call `Load` in the draw loop, that belongs in `LoadContent`.

Comment: Yes, I can provide the code for the buttons. BUT! I have figured out a way around, after the mainMenu has been drawn, spriteBatch.End(); and then call the Open again which ends at the bottom. For some reason, I don't yet understand but will question my tutor about, spriteBactch could only read one parameter type a time, calling one button.draw and SpriteBatch.Draw, or separated.

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed. One other thing to note, it seems odd that your various buttons aren't deriving from a base button class.

Comment: You see, because of the different size of each button. they are all arc shaped, one on top and two on the sides of a circle. I kept the borders to a minimum so they only light up when as close to them as possible. One is wider, the other two tall, and facing opposite ways, I found it much easier to copy paste the code and change the values. Also, my game deadline is 15th this month, if we don't get 5 day extension. It's not much more than a demo, but I will have to make a walkthrough video, and will put it on youtube as well, will post the link here if you are interested